# What is this small gray box on the top left corner?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I've got this small gray box on the top-left corner that stays above all windows. Right-clicking etc on it does nothing.

[image: gray box]

You can see it on top of the recycle bin icon in the pic above. What is that? I checked the Users tab on task manager and I was the only user running, I tried closing a bunch of running apps in system tray, etc.

Comment: Does it stay if you reboot computer?

Comment: It looks like you have 2 files in the recycle bin. If you empty the recycle bin, it should change to zero.

Comment: @LDC3, author says `stays above all windows`. I am not a Windows user, so I might be wrong, but I think such an indicator would not stay above all windows.

Comment: @Nikolay I'm with you, I'm just guessing. But that is what it looks like.

Comment: @LDC3: I don't agree. It looks like a remnant of a tooltip or GUI element from some  opened application that for some strange reason couldn't retain it's relative GUI elements when it was moved or closed. This happens sometimes. That's why it's interesting to know if it stays this way after a reboot. Or, maybe an easier way to test: just move the Recycle Bin icon and see if the number moves with it. But my guess is that it has nothing to do with the Bin.

Comment: Recycling bin has 617 items in it... moving recycling bin doesn't move the box. It stays above all windows, even when I go fullscreen. I will try a restart after 3ds max finishes rendering... which should be in about 7 hours. :\

Comment: Meanwhile, another option which might be less intrusive than a full reboot, may be to log in as a different user.  See if the number shows up then (or on the screen when switching between users).  The graphic shown is kinda hard to see when small; showing the grey box over a white screen might be easier for people to see.  (I struggled with it a bit before I could see/notice the  box).  If we could see what processes are being run, that might be helpful; this might not be an error/bug, but an intentional message from some program that is being run.